# Avoid ionic side menu from close when click on it

Tags: html, forms, ionic-framework, hamburger-menu

I'm developing with Ionic Framework an app where the main view is a map (working with Leaflet). And in the side menu, there are some forms in order to allow differente searches on the map (shortest path between 2 points...).

The thing is, every time I click in one of the inputs (text, checkbox...) of the forms, the side menu closes.

Is there anyway to avoid that? It is possible that the side menu only closes and shows when I tap in the 'burguer' button?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you have found any solutions ?

Comment: @toregua yes, the one I posted as answer

Comment: Even if i remove the close-menu directive I continue to have the problem. I have bypassed my issue by changing my menu in order to not use slide with form inside. In my context I finaly use a simple view now. thank you anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as simple as **remove the *'close-menu'*** class from all the *'ion-item'* elements inside the *ion-side-menu*